# ¿Cómo hacer invisibles unos sprites en Unity 2D?

Tags: unity, unity2d

Tengo un proyecto en Unity 2D de un juego de plataformas. Lo que busco hacer ahora es crear un scrip que haga que cuando el personaje entre en contacto con un Box Collider 2D aparezca a su espalda una columna para impedirle salir de la zona. Mi pregunta es doble. Primero: ¿Qué tengo que poner para que en el script me detecte la colisión del jugador con el Box collider? Y segundo: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el jugador no se quede atascado cuando choca con el collider?

Adjunto imágenes para explicar el problema:

Aquí tengo puesto el box collider. Los sprites aparecen en invisible para que el personaje pueda pasar a través de ahí, pero una vez choque contra el collider, entonces aparecerá una barrera a su espalda, impidiéndole volver atrás.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría lograr esto? ¿Y cómo desactivar el collider para que el personaje pueda seguir avanzando?

Answer (score 1):

lo primero es que el colider debes configurarlo desde el inspector para que sea traspasable (`IsTrigger = true`) es decir que el checkBox este seleccionado, ya eso lo hace traspasable.

para activar la columna que va quedando atrás no uses colisiones, usa triggers

Referencia:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html

Ejemplo:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
    {
        // si el objeto que traspasó es el jugador
        if(other.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
          // Activar columna   
        }
    }
}
```

Usas este método para detectar cuando un objeto atraviesa al otro (este fragmento de codigo debe ir en el objeto portador del colider invisible) cuando detecte que el personaje

Recuerda que el personaje también debe tener su propio colider, y si colocas un rigibody al objeto invisible en el inspector debes modificar la gravedad en una propiedad de la componente rigibody llamada (Gravity Scale, hacerla igual a 0)

Answer (score 0):

Script básico de como sería:

```
...
public GameObject Pared;

void Start(){
Pared.SetActive(false); //El set active activa o desactiva el GameObject
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){
if(coll.gameobject.tag = "Activador"){
Pared.SetActive(true);
}
}
```

Puedes reemplazar el *gameobject.tag* por *gameobject.name* , la única diferencia es que en uno tienes que poner el nombre del gameobject que colisiona y el otro tienes que ingresar el nametag.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Saludos.